# .Net Control Id like text box access original Id c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to retain controls id. e.g

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" />
```

When I use F12 it show its id different as "ct00_Main_myTextBox" is there any way to set it as
"yTextBox", I know its due to master page.

Thanks.

Comment: In which scenario is this an issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to Static.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

If you are trying to reference this in javascript, you could also use the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property to  get the generated ID, regardless of the ClientIDMode.

```
document.getElementById("<%= myTextBox.ClientID %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

keep `ClientIDMode="Static"`  and follow the rest as suggested by jrummell in his reply

I would also recommend you to read this article [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article838-aspnet-40-manipulate-clientid-using-clientidmode.aspx)